# How to pass data from a dropdown to my controller

Tags: laravel

I'm currently working on a data table where each item gets a dropdown menu that lets you choose options to change the status of the item in the DB. 
I'm triggering the function with a submit button, that shows the current status of the item in the DB (marked or not marked).
My problem is that passing the data (value from dropdown) to my controller is not working. Even trying to print the request with `dd($request->all())` shows me nothing.

Routes

```php
Route::any('/mark_as_important/{id}', 'ServiceController@markAsImportant')->middleware('all_customer');
```

Controller

```php
public function markAsImportant(Request $request, $id){
    try{
        dd($request);
        DB::table('tubes')->where('TubeID',$id)->update(['LOG_important'=>1]);
        return 'true';
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        return 'false';
    }
}
```

View

```
        <button type='submit' id="button_{{$row['TubeID']}}" onclick="markAsImportant({{$row['TubeID']}})"
        @if ($row['LOG_important'] == 1)
        disabled>Marked Important</button>
        @elseif ($row['LOG_important'] == 2)
        disabled>Marked RnD</button>
        @else
        >Mark as</button>
        <select name="flags" class="form-control" data-id='flag_field'>
          @php
          $sql = DB::table('flags')->select('id', 'Flag_Name')->get();
          @endphp
          @foreach ($sql as $row)
          <option value='{{$row->id}}'>{{$row->Flag_Name}}</option>;
          @endforeach
        </select>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function markAsImportant(id) {
    $("#button_" + id).attr('disabled', 'true');
    var flag_id = $(this).data("id")

    $.get("/mark_as_important/" + id, function(success) {
      if (success == 'true') {
        $("#button_" + id).html('Marked');
      // } else {
      //   alert('Something went wrong');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: why not just set the onclick with jquery instead of inline? also when you are saying `$(this).data('id')`, `$(this)` should be referring to the`<button>` which doesn't have an a `data-id` attr, the `<select>` does. Have you tried grabbing the `data-id` with some like `var flag_id = $('.form-control').data('id');` also you two name properties on the `<select>`

Comment: How could I set it with jquery? The data('id') should be referring to the ids of my select. I did try something like that but still couldn't see anything on my $request. Oh yes, thanks for pointing that out, already fixed that.   @MichaelCacciano

Answer (score 2):

to use jquery for the click event and change do the `$('#button_' + id).html()` you could try something like

```
$(`#button_${id}`).on('click', function() { 
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  var flagId = $('.form-control').data('id');

  console.log({ flagId: flagId, buttonDisabled: $(this).prop('disabled') }) 
  // make sure something is actually coming through with the console.log()

  $.ajax({
   url: `/mark_as_important/${id}`,
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json', // assuming its json
   success: function(result) {
     $(`#button_${id}`).html('Marked');
   },
   error: function(err) {
     console.log(err);
   }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a get request to an any route, the id is included on the url so you can grab it like this:

```php
$tubeId = request()->route('id');
```

But I would define the route as a get route, and get the data using [route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: tubeID is the id of the item. I want to get the one from the select menu. I will try with the get route, thanks

Comment: tubeId is just a variable name I decided, if you prefer: `DB::table('tubes')->where('TubeID', request()->route('id'))->update(['LOG_important'=>1]);`

Comment: tried the get route, but cannot get the id of the item I select on the dropdown. I can only get the Id that I included on the URL.